# Is it possible to send custom events to GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Looks like GA4 requires you to pre-define the customized strings in the admin console before being able to send them.

But sometimes I want to track very trivia and minor content on the pages.

There could be a lot of strings to send. In GA UA it's quite simple, just something like:

`ga('pageview', 'page'+string);`

But in GA4, how can I do that? Is the feature removed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a misunderstand about the event parameter

You can create a dimension AKA event parameter in `admin -> custom definition`

It is kind of a slot. Then you can send any value related the slot with only one configuration. No need to create as mush slot as you sent the value

```
event : "page_view",
page_custom_type : "some string 1"
```

```
event : "page_view",
page_custom_type : "some string 2"
```